# One url for login and dashboard

Tags: laravel-5

I want make one url for login and dashboard page example "/admin".
In all guides login page has different url with dashboard page example "/login" or "/admin/login". If our dashboard has url "admin" and I not auth, Middleware class Authenticate do

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

I try change it

```
return redirect()->action('AuthController@getLogin');
```

where getLogin

```
return view('auth.login');
```

but this call error Action getLogin not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function responsible for this route do something like :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     if(Auth::check())
      {
         //fetch data for dashboard
         //return view('dashboard');
      }
      else
      {
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
        {
          //fetch dash board data and return the view
        }
      }

}
```